# IE11 extension installation msi project

Tags: windows-installer, internet-explorer-11, add-on

I have an IE11 extension project what I want to install by msi project.
I created an msi project, I added the GAC folder and the Primary output into it.
I created the necessary registry keys and values and this msi project builded without any errors or warnings.
I could run the msi with no problems, but the dll did not get into GAC and the extension is not found in IE11.
I do not undersand.
How can I install IE11 extension with MSI installer, please?

**UPDATE**

It is interesting that the installer installes the extension in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\Extension\ folder and not in GAC.

Comment: Do you want to install assembly into GAC? If so, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac). IE is going to retire next year, so there's not much information about IE addons online. I find [an article](https://www.add-in-express.com/docs/internet-explorer-addons-deployment.php) about creating IE addon msi installers and you can also refer to it.

Comment: Thenk you for your answer. I gave up to bother with msi rather I did it with the help of the PowerShell.

Comment: OK. You can put your PowerShell solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.